# Onbeforeunload doesn't work if user go back

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using

```
 $(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
        $.post("save.php",{name:moves});
 });
```

It works very well but only if user closes the page. If user go back or type another website , it doesn't work. Which event should I use ? (It should fire when user leaves)

Comment: Did you try this online? I had a similar issue while I was developing offline, which did not happen in the online version.

Comment: are you sure the whole function is not called, or is only the post not executed?

Comment: I have noticed that only post not executed.

Answer (score -1):

You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116446/what-is-the-best-back-button-jquery-plugin) very interesting. :)

The above thread boiled down to [this](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/), a plugin called Asual.

My 10 cents on this plugin. Well written, well maintained, highly flexible plugin with a great reference API which made it really easy to implement.